# Unable to build a Release Signed Bundle(.aab) even though release.keystore file is exists

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

I have accidentally deleted `.android` folder. Then I have removed `Android Studio` completely from my Mac and then installed newly. Then I tried to create `release signed bundle` from `Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK` and given all the required details like `release keystore` file path, `alias` and `password`. Then I tired to generate `.apk` from `.aab` by using following command,

```
sudo bundletool build-apks --bundle=<.aab location> --output=<.apk location>
```

Then I got following message in terminal

```
INFO: The APKs will be signed with the debug keystore found at '/Users/<myfolder>/.android/debug.keystore'.
```

From the above message I understood that, `keystore` files are taken from `.android` folder. But in my `.android` folder only `debug.keystore` file is available, but not `release.keystore` file.

I assume this is the reason why i am unable to generate `release signed bundle`. If I am right,

1. How to have `release.keystore` file inside `.android` folder(I have a copy of `release.keystore` in `android/app/release.keystore`)?

Note: I am unable to generate `release signed bundle` since the time I deleted `.android` folder. Before that everything was just fine.

Comment: While are you generating **Signed Bundle/ APK** have you got any error or warning

Comment: Why you're building with `sudo`? This provides no meaning at all.

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` module app, let add some lines of code below:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       storeFile file('YOUR_KEYSTORE_FILE')
       storePassword YOUR_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias YOUR_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword YOUR_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```

And then retry the build `aab` command.